# History API - Ajax pages + Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, history

I have a structure of my site like this [IMAGE](http://s27.postimg.org/v89zjnxhf/Schermata_2015_05_09_alle_15_09_23.png)
I'm trying to create some page transition with ajax & history API

CODE:

```
history.pushState(null, null, "/members/" + dataLink + ".php" ); // update URL
console.log(dataLink);
$(".ajax-container").load('/members/single.php', function(){
     fillPage(dataLink); // load datas from json
});
```

Everything works fine, I can load the page correctly with datas but now I have to implement the behavior of the back button (using history api / popstate )but I've no idea how to do that because every member-page in filled with data from json.

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
 // what inside here? It should call the previous page + the data from json like the previous ajax call
});
```

Any ideas? 
EDIT: like you can see the only page I really call is `single.php` filled with new datas everytime. Maybe is here the problem?

EDIT 2 & IDEA: maybe I can store the current & previous page 2 var, and when call the event popstate run fillpage() with the previous variable (in simply words the previous name) and add a check if the previous page is home, in that case load home.php
Is this such a bad idea?

### SOLVED:

I create a custom property `backlink` where I store the name of the page of where I am

```
$(".ajax-container").load('/home.php', function(data){
                    history.pushState({url: 'home.php', backLink: dataLink}, null, "/" );
```

and then I make a check on the `popstate`

```
if (state.backLink != "home"){
                $(".ajax-container").load('thesinglepage.php', function(){
                    ...
            }else{
                $(".ajax-container").load('/home.php', function(){
                    ...
                });
            }
```

Comment: can you edit your title to small caps? Thankyou :)

Comment: shame on me, I didn't turn off the caps locker :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1) When you call pushstate, you can store an object data on the first parameter. In this object you can store a key representing the page (for example what you want: "mypage.php" where "mypage" is a dynamic page).

Then, when you go back on your history, you can access to "event.state" like this:

```
history.pushState({url: dataLink + '.php'}, null, "/members/" + dataLink + ".php" );
    window.popstate = function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        console.log(e.state); // here we have previous object data store on pushstate url
        /* Here, call again $('.ajax-container').load(function() { fillpage(state.fillpage); }) */
    }
```

2) Save pushsate after ajax call passing load url + data. Doing this, you could call fillpage without doing the ajax call:

```
$(".ajax-container").load('/members/single.php', function(data){
    history.pushState({url: dataLink + '.php', dataLink: data}, null, "/members/" + dataLink + ".php" );
    fillPage(dataLink); // load datas from json
});

window.popstate = function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    console.log(e.state); // here we have previous object data store after ajax event
    /* Here, call directy fillpage(state.fillpageData); */
}
```

**UPDATED**
I created a real example (working right on my computer at least) to show you push and pop state functionality. At this example, I did calls using jsonp (but it's not important for the case). If you have doubts don't hesitate to ask :)
http://pastebin.com/98iN9UDf

Comment: what are the differences between these options? which one is better? btw thank's :) I'm going to try now!

Comment: It's depends. If you want to cache data, option 2 is the best but if you wan't or you can't cache data then option 1.

Comment: I'm working on that but in both of cases the console.log is "undefined"

Comment: I updated my entry to show you a real example. I hope that it will be enough for you.

Comment: really thanks for that, but I solved in another way :) but you explanation + code was very USEFUL :)